# Remove or hide fields with value 0 in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have the following Grafana panel that shows the steps of a download process in which the process has failed. It's implementation in the source Application is done through Micrometer facade in a Spring Boot Application to persist data in Prometheus:

```
Counter
        .builder(Metric.RDL_FAILURE_REASON_COUNTER.getName())
        .baseUnit("fails")
        .tag("type_of_failure", failReason)
        .tag("step", step)
        .register(meterRegistry)
        .increment();
```

It creates a counter or increments an existing one per each pair tag-value given. In Grafana I generated the following panel:

[image]

In this case I'm just using the step tag to filter doing the following promQL query:

```
sum(metric_name{application="application_name", instance=~"$server"}) by (step_name)
```

However, this is for all events registered ever in development environment. I would like to have also this pie chart but just with the last 24h failed attempts. In other words, knowing in which steps the last 24h downloads have failed. I tried adding increase method to this query:

```
sum(increase(metric_name{application="application_name", instance=~"$server"}[24h])) by (step)
```

And it's giving me this pie chart:

[image]

Although the result is correct it's not good to have all this rows with 0 in the value and 0%. This pie chart has a low number of possible values and it's not a problem but I intend to have this last 24h results for more metrics and I can not afford having 30-40 rows with just 0. Is there any way of hide or remove it from the query result?

Already tried applying a filter by value transformation to exclude values equal to 0 but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `!= 0` in the end of you query to remove the zero values:

```
sum(increase(metric_name{application="application_name", instance=~"$server"}[24h])) by (step) != 0
```

This will remove the the zero values of your pie chart.

Comment: Why this tip isn't in any of the official docs is beyond me. You saved my bacon. Thank you.